# Creating a form builder for a CMS in Zend?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

Good Day,

I have created a `CMS` to display pages however I now see that the users want to be able to insert `custom forms` with fields of their choosing.

I am thinking the `form fields` should be added to a `fields` table that is linked to a `forms` table. Where things such as the field datatypes and validation as well as whether the info should be stored in the database or an email address to send the form to would be stored and then used to generate the form in the front end of the CMS.

Now for displaying the actual form in a page...
How would a user set where the field should be within the content? All I have right now is a `text editor (ckeditor)` where the users can change the content to display...how could they tell the CMS to put a form in that particular page and how would the CMS know to add the form to a specific page?

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way:
Split up all different HTML nodes to basic php Objects like radiobutton, checkbox, select, file, textarea and input.
Supply them each with some validation like entered integer. Pass them on the a form constructing class using their built in representation.

Hard Way:
The other way is by logically splitting up the data that is supplied, so lists, text, files, and one choice. 
Text can have multiple subtypes as integer, float, date email, what you like (a regex validator for PHP is very nice here). Also for some you might store the choices available or some domain,... .

For some of these Types you have different options to render them on your website, i.e. a list can be multiple input elements, one textarea with a delimiter or just a multi-selectbox.
So you propably want to make these indepentend from the datatypes they represents, meaning you need classes that render the HTML for these basic datatypes (Adapters).

These adapters will be constructed by getting one datatype object, render the HTML called by some form object, than convert the data and send it to the datatypes. These will then validate them and store them in your database or whatever.

I think the most complex part would be putting this together with javascript validation, put you might just enable this for certain adapters and datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

As @mjb4 said you can create your own form class. The class can add new form elements and every form element is a object inside the class. I have done this myself and it is very handy.

**PHP**

The form itself is saved in the database and can be loaded by the form class. It initiates the corresponding class for every form element. Then you can change individual form properties. You can also add new form elements or remove some.

With the method `$html = $form->getHTML();` you can grab the html. What is does is simply loop through all the form element objects and calls their getHTML method.

When sending the form you again use the class to validate. It loops through all the form elements and calls their validateMe method. Every object knows which name the form element has and looks for it in the `$_REQUEST` array.

**Jquery cms side**

You can use Jquery to create a form creator and save the form scheme into a database. Give users two options to save the form data to. One: email the form data. Two: Create new db table and insert data with unique id. When giving option two there also should be a report creator which creates a page (public or private) which shows the form data.

Also you should leave the html structure to you php class. There is no need for the users to change that. Just create one template for them witch styling.

Answer (score 0):

**Domain Objects**

Depending on the flexibility you desire, you will need to create a number of Entities/Domain objects which will hold the users custom form data.

To begin with, entities that represent the form elements. I would create `Form`, `Fieldsets`, `Fields` and `FieldTypes`. Each form has 1 or more fieldsets, each fieldset has one or more Fields etc.

I am actually building a form builder in ZF2 as my companies current project, I started out with a generic element that could be extended for all forms 'elements'

```
/**
 * Base form element that all form elements extend
 */
abstract class Element implements ElementInterface, AttributeCollectionAwareInterface
{
  /**
   * @var string
   * @ODM\Id
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @var string
   * @ODM\Field(type="string")
   */
  protected $name; 

  /**
   * @var string
   * @ODM\Field(type="string")
   */
  protected $label;

  /**
   * $attributes
   *
   * Map of form element attributes
   * 
   * @var array
   * @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="JobboardBase\Document\Form\Attribute")
   */
  protected $attributes;

  /**
   * $options
   *
   * Map of form element options
   * 
   * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
   * @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="JobboardBase\Document\Form\Option")
   */
  protected $options;

  /**
   * @var status
   * 
   * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="JobboardBase\Document\Form\Status")
   */
  protected $status;

  /**
   * $dateCreated
   *
   * The form creation date
   * 
   * @var \MongoDate
   * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
   * @ODM\Field(type="date")
   */
  protected $dateCreated;

  /**
   * $dateUpdated
   *
   * The form updated date
   * 
   * @var \MongoDate
   * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
   * @ODM\Field(type="date")
   */
  protected $dateUpdated;
```

These entities should have properties that map as closely as possible to Zend's already existing `Zend_Form_Element_*` classes (such as `$attributes`, `$name`, `$options` etc) This will help you when you need to render them on the page.

**Placeholders**

Most CMS systems have some kind of "placeholder" functionality - The 'page' is broken down into several 'locations' such as header, footer, title, content etc. Again these 'locations' could be modeled as entities that are editable by your users, where they would be able to 'assign' one or more 'content items' to each placeholder, such as your form.

The basic idea is really a way of composing a page view based upon multiple other view files (kind of like a view partial) where the content within is dynamically generated based on the configuration.

Fortunately, the Zend Framework also offers the ability to create such placeholders. [Their documentation says](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.view.placeholders.basics.html):

> View placeholders are a simple and powerful method for creating rich layouts for your application. You can use a variety of standard placeholders, such as those discussed ( doctype(), headTitle(), headLink(), and headScript()), or use the generic placeholder() helper to aggregate content and render it in custom ways.

**Templating**

Placeholders may help you locate content in set areas. However, this method would not work if a user wishes to render the form directly within the text content (your ckeditor).

One solution would be to implement some kind of template system for your forms, where a set text template is placed in the content.

For example:

> "This is my contact us [FORM][id=123][name=contact-us][FORM] form please fill in all the fields"

When you *render* the form you replace this template with the actual form HTML. This method can work well providing you are creative on the template to ensure no false positives, and perhaps some JS 'add form' button to create the template text for user.

Answer (score 0):

One Possible solution for you:

Each form your client will create will have a unique name or ID.

they will use the CMS to edit content of the pages. they will place a unique code (agreed format) in place where they would like the from to appear.

ex.

```
##FORM_CONTINER_CONTACT_US##  // in this case the form is contact us based on ##FORM_CONTINER_XXXX## where XXX could be string or Id.
```

After the content of the page was pulled from database you pass it to new function

```
public function insertFormContiner($pageContetnt)
{
    // find the form container in $pageContent use regular expression to find it
    // get the unique name of the form container CONTACT_US in this case
    // build the form from the database (get the full html) 
    // replace the new created from with ##FORM_CONTINER_CONTACT_US## in this case

    // view the finale content of the page
    return $pageContent;
}
```

NOTE: you will need to build other function(s) to process the form on submission.